# ¿Qué significa "pan con moringa"?

Tags: significado, coloquialismos, adjetivos, cuba

En Cuba oí la frase:

> compré pan con moringa

También, el uso de la palabra ‘moringa’ como un adjetivo para describir a una persona.

Cuando pregunté sobre el significado, todo el mundo se rió pero no me lo explicó. ¿Puede ser que tenga un significado un poco grosero?

Edit: como contexto, oí la frase por primera vez en Santiago de Cuba un día poco después de la Navidad, cuando había un escasez de los panecillos normales en la cuidad debido a que se escaseaba la harina. Compré una barra de pan blanco con forma de cilindro plano con extremos puntiagudos y mi amigos la llamaron ‘pan con moringa’. Volví a preguntárles el significado algunas veces pero aparte de las risas nunca me lo explicaron.

Comment: ¿Puede que fuera [_moñinga_](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=kR7ySPEUMx0A5tWGqk3) o [_moronga_](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=ngKOfNqZzx0AnaePPlv|OzPuhFIg7x0Ag6d8VEs)?

Comment: @fedorqui la harina de moringa se comercializa y existen recetas de [pan con moringa](https://pandecalidad.com/pan-con-moringa), no veo que por ahí tenga ningún significado especial. La moringa o [ben](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5L6NzOi) es un árbol de climas intertropicales. Por lo visto Fidel Castro [la consideraba](https://www.bbc.com/mundo/noticias/2016/01/160118_salud_moringa_planta_venezuela_lb) una "planta milagrosa" y la razón de su curación, y pretendía plantar moringa por todo el país al ser considerada materia prima para complementos alimenticios.

Comment: @Charlie entiendo. Lo digo porque en el DAMER no encontré _moringa_ (que [sí está en el DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PpmdmrC)) y la opción _moñinga_ (nuestra _boñiga_) me pareció que encajaba con el hecho de que los locales rieran al oirlo.

Comment: Moringa es una planta. El comentario de @Charlie deberia convertirse en respuesta. Fotos y explicación aquí https://mx.activo.news/nutricion/para-que-sirve-la-moringa/

Comment: @DGaleano no lo he puesto como respuesta porque no he visto la palabra _moringa_ aplicada a personas, como dice la pregunta, ni tampoco que pueda tener un significado grosero. Puede que en Cuba tenga alguna connotación especial que desconozco, de ahí que solo lo haya planteado como comentario.

Comment: Lo único que he encontrado son algunos artículos que dicen que tiene propiedades afrodisiacas o que ayuda a combatir la disfunción eréctil. Aparte de eso no parece que tenga ningún doble sentido pero mejor si algún cubano nos saca de dudas

Comment: Releyendo la pregunta creo que lo que falta es contexto. Si estaban hablando de afrodisíacos y disfunción, eso es lo que puede haber causado la risa y la falta de voluntad de darles explicaciones a un turista. No es que sea una palabra grosera.

Comment: https://pandecalidad.com/pan-con-moringa en España.   Parece que tiene algo que ver con la diversidad sexual: https://observatoriocriticocuba.org/tag/orientacion-sexual/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El pan que compró tenía puntos duros y sus amigos lo llamaron "pan con moringa". Creo que fuera una broma sexual. Ya quedó notado que la moringa tiene fama de afrodisíaco. El pan debió recordarles de un pene túmido, como si se hubiera fortalecido o endurecido con moringa.

Nada que ver con ["pan con moringa"](https://pandecalidad.com/pan-con-moringa) en sentido literal. Ese pan fue antromorfizado.

Answer (score 0):

En el internet veo que la moringa se recomienda usar como ingrediente para aumentar el valor nutritivo de varias recetas.  También se recomienda para mejorar la experiencia sexual, principalmente del hombre.  Por ejemplo: https://okdiario.com/salud/2017/05/25/moringa-propiedades-2798664

Creo que por lo último se reían.  Quizás habían visto todos el mismo anuncio en la tele, el periódico, o la farmacia, y les daba pena explicar.

¿Cómo descubrí esto?  Buscando con google: `moringa sexual`.